# Sending array of int as @QueryParam in Jersey

Tags: java, jersey

I am trying to write a GET method and send array of int's as QueryParam to it. This is how I am trying to do:

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response test(@Context HttpServletRequest request,
        @QueryParam("list") final int list[])
{
    System.out.println(list.length);
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

This results in 500 Internal Server error.When I tried using List of Integer, it worked perfectly. Doesn't Jersey support array as parameter or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: have your try @QueryParam("list") Set<String> list?

Comment: @JekinKalariya I need to pass array of int's, why would i try that?

Comment: jersy will convert array to list or set just try if its work or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implementation of this in jersey which is not supporting array as a parameter. As you need to pass it as an array just pass it by converting the list to array by using **`Arrays.asList(arr)`**

The java doc say that the type of method parameter should be :

```
1) Be a primitive type;
2) Have a constructor that accepts a single String argument;
3) Have a static method named valueOf or fromString that accepts a single String argument (see, for example, Integer.valueOf(String))
4) Be List, Set or SortedSet, where T satisfies 2 or 3 above. The resulting collection is read-only.
```

Sometimes parameters may contain more than one value for the same name. If this is the case then types in 4) may be used to obtain all values.

So using an array would not be possible in this case.